# Returning all columns of output only if contents in second column have a positive number

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm looking for a way to return a line only if the second column returns a positive number value. In the example below...

```
PID Status  Label
-   0   com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon
937 0   com.wacom.TabletDriver.126696
-   0   com.apple.quicklook
-   0   com.apple.parentalcontrols.check
715 48  com.apple.Finder
-   0   com.apple.PackageKit.InstallStatus
-   0   com.apple.FontWorker
786 -44 com.apple.bird
-   0   com.apple.familycontrols.useragent
-   0   com.apple.aos.migrate
-   0   com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarn
839 -44 com.apple.nsurlsessiond
```

I'd want a command that results in:

```
PID Status  Label
715 48  com.apple.Finder
```

I've been pulling my hair out trying to find a way to do this piping through AWK, SED, GREP, RegEx, etc. I am unable get the desired results.

I've tried things like:

`launchctl list |  awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i>=1) print $i} '` but the results are no longer in a table and are returned in an unreadable format, as well as I'm getting positive numbers back from column PID/$1 when I'd like to only get results if under the Status/$2 column.

Starting with `launchctl list | awk '{ print $2 }'` but if I pipe it through anything else like GREP/SED I'm obviously not able to get the other missing columns as the data has already been stripped out. I'm not expert, and maybe I'm just missing a key flow | through | piping commands to get what I want, so I'm asking for any assistance or expertise to help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
launchctl list | awk 'NR==1 || $2>0'
PID Status  Label
715 48  com.apple.Finder
```

To format it in a table use:

```
launchctl list | awk 'NR==1 || $2>0' | column -t
PID  Status  Label
715  48      com.apple.Finder
```

Comment: Beautiful solutions, thank you! Can you elaborate at all as to explain how `awk` is achieving that? Thanks again for the fastest ever answer ;-) EDIT: Makes sense, just by looking at it again and the little I do know about `awk`. Sweet, great solution and lesson learned.

Comment: This is a simple awk command. `NR==1` just matches first row and `$2>0` matches condition of 2nd column great than zero. `column -t` is used for formatting the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
launchctl list | sed '1b
     /^[-0-9]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}[-0]/d'
```

- sed posix version
- keep header (even it is not a positive number in second column)